# Tool for finding all references in C# source code

Tags: c#, source-code, code-analysis

I need a tool (free or paid) similar to Visual Studio "Find all references".
It needs to analyze set of C# source code files and list all types that are defined in the source code. For each type list the locations in source code where it is used and do the same for all protected/internal/public members of each type.

Something like:

```
Class1
    Used in: file2.cs, line no: 11; file3.cs, line no: 23
    property Prop1
        Used in: file2.cs, line no: 16; file3.cs, line no: 27
    method Method1
        Used in: file2.cs, line no: 12; file3.cs, line no: 25
```